Setting breakpoint() in pytest breaks within called functions rather than test function itself
When I set a breakpoint in my pytest test functions, it seems to be debugging within the functions called by test rather than the test itself:
def test_my_function():
    test_value = np.random.choice(...)
    breakpoint()

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PDB set_trace (IO-capturing turned off) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
--Call--
> .../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/_core/fromnumeric.py(3063)_prod_dispatcher()

Where the expected behavior would be to be able to work at the level of test_my_function in the debugger, but I'm being brought into the numpy package.
Anyone know why this could be happening?

If you add a pass as the last line of the function, after the call to breakpoint(), does it work as you expect?

@larsks It does! Why is this so?

I have never bothered investigating in any detail; I just know that I get weird behavior when breakpoint() is the last line of a test function.
